# web2py - translate data inside dropdowns

Tags: web2py

How to translate data in dropdowns.

e.g: if i have table region that contains all regions. i want to translate these regions into other languages.

Is there any way like T to translate them??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it depends on where the data comes from. Say you have a table in the form

```
a=[["this", "is"],["a", "test"]]
```

You can do something like this in the view:

```
{{=TABLE(*[TR(*[TD(T(x)) for x in row]) for row in a])}}
```

After you run it all the strings will popup in the translation page in the administrative interface.